# provlem with ajax returning the whole html code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to get some data by ajax

```
var ajax1 = false;
ajax1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax1.open("GET","ajax/getolinedata.php");
ajax1.onreadystatechange = function(){
    var mylink = ajax1.responseText;
    $("a[goal='online']").attr("href",mylink);
}
ajax1.send(null);
```

and this is the php code returning the data

```
    while($cartRow = mysql_fetch_array($getCartR)){
    $pro_name = $cartRow['Product_Name'];
    if(strstr($pro_name," ")){
        $pro_name = str_replace(" ","_",$cartRow['Product_Name']);
    }
    $lin .= "&li_".$x."_type=product&li_".$x."_price=".$cartRow['Product_Price']."&li_".$x."_quantity=".$cartRow['Quantity']."&li_".$x."_name=".$pro_name."&li_".$x."_tangible=N";
    $x++;
}
echo $lin;
```

but the result is this

```
<a href="&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN&quot;&quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-Transitional.dtd&quot;&gt;&lt;html xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml&quot;&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;meta http-equiv=&quot;Content-Type&quot; content=&quot;text/html; charset=utf-8&quot;/&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase?sid=123456&amp;mode=2CO&amp;li_0_type=product&amp;li_0_price=3700&amp;li_0_quantity=1&amp;li_0_name=iphone_4&amp;li_0_tangible=N&amp;li_1_type=product&amp;li_1_price=3000&amp;li_1_quantity=1&amp;li_1_name=Lumia_720&amp;li_1_tangible=N&amp;li_2_type=product&amp;li_2_price=4500&amp;li_2_quantity=1&amp;li_2_name=ipad_2&amp;li_2_tangible=N&amp;li_3_type=product&amp;li_3_price=2000&amp;li_3_quantity=2&amp;li_3_name=Lumia_520&amp;li_3_tangible=N" goal="online"><img src="images/online.jpg"></a>
```

it's returning the whole html while there's no html code in that php page at all it's just php codes to connect to the database and fetch data any help ?

Comment: You've tagged this as jquery. Would you not use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ to make the ajax requests?

Comment: why ain't you using jauery.ajax ??

Comment: thanks so much you all helped my and it's solved.

Comment: Please mark the answer as solved then, using the checkbox infront of the answer.

Comment: @jq beginner   Try to mention how it got solved or accept an answer so that it will be helpful to others having the same problem. Cheers!

Comment: my connection.php file which is used to connect to the database had html code so i deleted it and everything is now fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ajax/getolinedata.php if you have html code or echo html code, it will return the HTML code too.

Try opening ajax/getolinedata.php directly on your browser. If you get HTML page, then the same will be sent to ajax request.

So, try echoing only information that is needed and you should be good.

Also don't forget to set response type in header. For example if you are returning json data, use:

header('Content-type: text/json');

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure You didn't print the html in config file or constructor or something like that. 
I got the the same problem. 
Solution is to create separate file to handle the ajax request.